# Exit a batch script that called another batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, call, parent

I have a batch script that calls a sequence of batch files.

There is an error case where I need to exit the batch file that was called, as well as the parent batch file. Is it possible to accomplish this inside the child batch file?

#### test.bat

```
rem Test1.bat will exit with error code.
call test1.bat
rem Want script to stop if test1.bat errors.
call test2.bat
```

#### test1.bat

```
rem Can I get test.bat to terminate from inside test1.bat?
exit /b 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, by using errorlevel. If the called batches systematically use `exit 0` to notify *keep on* and `exit 1` to ask caller to stop, you can modify the caller that way:

```
rem Test1.bat will exit with error code.
call test1.bat

rem Want script to stop if test1.bat errors.
if errorlevel 1 goto fatal
call test2.bat
exit 0
:fatal
echo Fatal error
exit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can exit all child and parent batch processes from the child by causing a fatal syntax error in the child:

#### test.bat

```
@echo off
echo before
call test1.bat
echo after
```

#### test1.bat

```
@echo off
echo in test 1
call :kill 2>nul

:kill - Kills all batch processing with a fatal syntax error
() rem fatal syntax error kills batch and all parents
```

Calling `test.bat` prints "before" and "in test 1", but not "after".